# Can't add facebook promoted_object field to campaign during graph api call for posting ads on facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I am working on facebook ads api and as new breaking changes

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.2#promoted_object

facebook has added new filed call promoted_object to campaign for some specific type of objective as.
Now my question is how can i add this field to graph api call when creating new campaign with valid objective, as i am using ruby on rails technology and fb_graph gem in order to communicate with graph api.As this field will be a json object so how can i add this json field with value using the fb_graph gem.The link might be like below

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcampaigns?[here i need to add this promoted_objective]".
```

But i can't add this filed to api call as i am using fb_graph gem.
Any one can help me regarding this.
thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

i have found out the solution,i needed to do monkey patch of my fb_graph gem.go to

```
 lib/fb_graph/ad_campaign.rb #inside external libraries
```

and added

```
:promoted_object
```

field to the attr_accessor block.
Then i can just add this promoted object filed as hash to the fb_graph object.

```
your_fb_graph_object.ad_campaigns(:promoted_object => 'VIDEO_VIEWS or something else')
```

the problem is solved.Keep in mind that this solution will work on fb_graph gem i am not sure if it will work at fb_graph2 gem because i did not test it on fb_graph2.